# What is the proper way to manage Java lifecycle in swig director wrappers when the underlying C++ layer holds references?

Tags: swig

Given an interface like

```
%feature("director") HeldBase;
%feature("smartptr") HeldBasePtr;   
typedef SmartPtr<HeldBase> HeldBasePtr;  // a minor wrapper around boost::shared_ptr
// Various typemaps that ensure Java-side HeldBase instances are always HeldBasePtr
class HeldBase {
public:
   virtual void doSomething(int) = 0;
}

class Holder {
   void hold(HeldBasePtr hb);
   void release(HeldBasePtr hb);
   void clear();
   void process(int seconds);
}
```

Now some code implements the HeldBase, on the java side doing something like:

```
class MyHeldBase: extends HeldBase { 
   void doSomething(int i) { System.out.println("Hello whirled"); }
}

Holder h = new Holder();
HeldBase local = new MyHeldBase();
h.hold(new MyHeldBase());
h.hold(local);
h.process(1000000);     // presumably doing something with the held things.
```

The underlying C++ layer deals with the smart pointers "properly", so (for example) destroying the Holder (swig proxy and underlying C++ object) correctly decrements the ref counts on the underlying smart pointers.

Right now the 'local' held base works fine, but the one without a reference held on the java-side gives a "null upcall" error presumably after some gc causes the java instance to go away.

I noticed the generated swigTakeOwnership and swigReleaseOwnership methods, and tracked them down in the code to be toggle whether a GlobalRef or GlobalWeakRef is held by the director.  So I did some wrapper code so that calls to hold(HeldBase hb) called hb.swigReleaseOwnership() and release() called hb.swigTakeOwnership().  Looking at the code it seemed that swigReleaseOwnership would convert the underlying director ref to a GlobalRef (so that the C++ layer would hold ownership of the Java MyHeldBase).  And vice-versa for swigTakeOwnership.

Unfortunately this didn't work for unrelated reasons...  something in our typemaps have rendered the swigTakeOwnership and swigReleaseOwnership uncallable, because they (think they) hold HeldBase *  not HeldBasePtr *.

If that is the right way to solve this problem, I'll try to track down why those methods are not being generated correctly.  But I still feel like there are unresolved issues (that are hard to think about.)

For example, what about:

```
HeldBase local = new MyHeldBase()
Holder h1 = new Holder(); Holder h2 = new Holder(); 
h1.hold(local);
h2.hold(local);
h1.release(local)
local = null;
```

In this case, the call to swigReleaseOwnership() happens twice, but the second is a noop.  When release() call swigTakeOwnership (making the reference back into a GlobalWeakRef) the java layer is once again "owning" and h2 will get a null upcall.  Also, if calls to swigTakeOwnership ARE required, then Holder.clear() seems to mean I need to add code to hold all the passed java-extended directors (at which point I can just do that to manage their lifecycle).

It "feels" like when using smart pointers with directors, the C++ side of the director should always just use a GlobalRef and things will "just work" but OTOH it seems that is a memory leak there since then the C++ side will keep the Java proxy alive and vice-versa.

Comment: Note, this may all be simply unsupported by swig (2.0.5 is the version we're using).  I think we had to patch swig to allow the director to hold a smart pointer.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that the C++ side ought to keep a reference to the Java implementation. It won't be a memory leak though - any Java proxy classes that get created won't be the same Java Object as the actual instance of the real implementation. Any chance you could expand your code into a complete example though? (e.g. a SWIG interface via `%inline` to give definitions as well as declarations and a Java 'runme' class that shows the problem). That would make it simpler for people to try things out.

Comment: I guess my first hope was for someone "experienced" to explain the motivation for swigReleaseOwnership() and swigTakeOwnership().  A couple people have worked on this here and I don't understand everything that was done, and (especially because of our patched swig) I'm not sure I can make an example that demonstrates the issue.  But I guess I should not be lazy, and will try (and maybe solve my own problem :) ).